# How to return any fields that were used to find a document with a find $or query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a simple / clean way to return the field that was used after successfully finding a document?

for example during signup , I'm checking if a email or username has been taken and want to notify the user which form field to correct

```
User.findOne( { $or :[ {'email': email} , {'username': username}] } ... callback =>
```

Comment: Why don't you set email or username as unique fields in your model. Whenever you try to save a duplicate entry, you can catch the error and return the error message

Comment: @AhmetTanakol I have that too, but on form submit response I want to tell the user what they did wrong.

Comment: I think a form validation library can be helpful in this case. Or, you can just define some checks for the fields you have such as required, min, max etc...

Answer (score 0):

You might check the email and then the username as follow:

```
const username;
const email = await User.findOne( {'email': email} )
if(!email) {
   username = await User.findOne( {'username': username} )
   if(!username) 
       ok
   return 'username taken'
}
return 'email taken'
```